# Using php creating file and adding text to it

Tags: php, linux, shell

I am trying to create a text file using php and the value is coming through a db call

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM topic_master");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$x1=$row{'code'};
exec("printf $x1 >> code.txt");
}
```

But the value is not inserted in the code.txt. Only array(code) is inserted in the code.txt.
Actually the $row{'code'} has "#xy { } () %". How can i write the values to txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use **$row{'code'}** the correct usage is **$row['code']**

Also, I would suggest using **file_put_contents()** instead of **exec** so you could do

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM topic_master");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$x1=$row['code'];
file_put_contents('code.txt',$x1, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: FILE_APPEND should be in file_input or content will be errased and only last line will be in the file

Comment: I think it will append data for every refresh of this page. same data will store every time

Comment: $x1="abc ";
 file_put_contents('code.txt',$x1, FILE_APPEND);
If you refresh page 3 time output will be 'abc abc abc' I think he did not want this

Comment: See the answer code.txt will contain amount of data which is in database in every refresh http://stackoverflow.com/a/18642996/2459296

Answer (score 3):

This will solve your problem:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM topic_master");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
file_put_contents('code.txt',$row['code'],FILE_APPEND);//FILE_APPEND is necessary
}
```

Comment: Same data will append in every refresh.

Comment: @Salim no , data change in each iteration,and File_APPEND put cursor in the end of file so data are not erased

Comment: $x1="abc "; file_put_contents('code.txt',$x1, FILE_APPEND); If you refresh page 3 times output will be 'abc abc abc'

Comment: @Salim OP have not said anything about this.He should specify what he wants,don't forget that database is not a variable and values change

Comment: no needs for `$x1=$row['code'];` every cycle. Just `file_put_contents('code.txt', $row['code'], FILE_APPEND);`. Mysql deprecated. Cyclic file access instead one save...

Answer (score 1):

Use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead of that exec and do

```
$s = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $x1=$row['code'];
    $s .= $x1 . "\n";
}
file_put_contents("code.txt", $s, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: WIth the `FILE_APPEND` flag to not erase the previous data

Comment: i think \r\n is better

Comment: @FaceOfJock Using `\r\n ` in Linux will produce undesirable results. This works fine for Windows, but not Linux.

Comment: @Fred-ii- but in notepad++ for example , \n will not pass to next line

Comment: @FaceOfJock What do you by *"will not pass to next line"*?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry for my english , i mean if you open file using notepad for example , you will see that all lines are in one line ,but if you use \r\n this is overpassed

Comment: @FaceOfJock Not a problem and thanks for the clarification and I now understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM topic_master");

// if you want to APPEND the data in code.txt, use this
// however, using that particular SQL query the same data will be written over and over because there's nothing specifying a parameter change
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $x1 = $row['code'];
    write_file('code.txt',$x1,'a');
}

// if you want to OVERWRITE the data in code.txt use this
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $x1 .= $row['code'];
}
write_file('code.txt',$x1,'w');


// function to write content to a file (with error checking)
function write_file($filename,$content,$flag) {
    if(is_writable($filename)) {
        if(!$handle = fopen($filename, $flag)) {
            // die, or (preferably) write to error handler function
            die('error');
        }
        if(fwrite($handle, $content) === FALSE) {
            // die, or (preferably) write to error handler function
            die('error');
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Edit: changed flag from w to a.

Another edit: if you want to APPEND to the file, leave the fopen() flag set to 'a'. If you want to overwrite the existing contents, change the flag to 'w'.

Final edit: added two versions with explanation

Comment: `w` will overwrite content. OP needs to append, therefore `a` or `a+`

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. Where does he state he needs to append?

Comment: You're welcome Tim. In the title *"Using php creating file and adding text to it"*

Comment: Yeah, it's not always clear when the important stuff is in the title and not the question body itself; an honest mistake ;-)

Comment: Totally confusing regardless, because "adding" can mean both. :)

Comment: Ahh... you have a point there! However, the OP did accept the one with `FILE_APPEND`, so I take it that's what the goal was, but again, you do have a point there. *"Touché"* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are not creating a text file using PHP, you are creating a text file using shell execution. Why don’t you just try file functions?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM topic_master");
$file = fopen("code.txt", "ab");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    fwrite($file, $row["code"]);
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: `"ab"`? `b` is for binary. Either `a` or `a+` if it's text, not the `b` switch.

Comment: [PHP manual](http://php.net/fopen) says, among other things: “For portability, it is strongly recommended that you always use the 'b' flag when opening files with fopen().”

Answer (score 0):

Get all data in a variable and write it in file

```
<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM topic_master");

$data = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $x1=$row['code'];

    $data .= $x1;

}

$fp = fopen("code.txt","w");

fwrite($fp,$data);

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: fwrite($fp,$data) instead of fwrite($fp,$x1) and also **$fp = fopen("code.txt","a");** to place pointer in end of file not in the beginning

Comment: @Salim `w` will overwrite content. OP needs to append, therefore `a` or `a+`

Comment: It is out of loop and all value stored in variable $data it is writing to file only once

Comment: @Salim As per OP's title *"Using php creating file and adding text to it"* See accepted answer, where it uses `FILE_APPEND`

Comment: Read comments in excepted answer